# What is an ultrametric normed vector space?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Wikipedia's article on [ultrametric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space) seems to suggest that an ultrametic space can also be a normed vector space.

It seems to be impossible for an ultrametric to be induced by a vector space norm, because if $v$ is a nonzero vector, then
$$d(0,2v)=\|2v\|=2\|v\|>\|v\|=\max(d(0,v),d(v,2v)) $$
contradicting $d$ being an ultrametric.

So what's going on there? Is there a concept of "normed vector space" that dispenses with the requirement that scalar multiplication scales the norm accordingly? (That would be more of a "normed abelian group", then).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct equality is $\|a v\|=|a|\|v\|$ for some [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29) $|\cdot|$ on the scalar field. Absolute values can be nonarchimedean and satisfy the ultrametric inequality. In such a case, $|k|\le 1$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$.

For instance, $\|(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\|:=\sqrt{|v_1|_p^2+\cdots+|v_n|_p^2}$ makes $\Bbb Q^n$ an ultrametric normed vector space over $\Bbb Q$, where $|\cdot|_p$ stands for the [$p$-adic absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#p-adic_Norm).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.